# Also how many permutations of the number sequence are there in which the score is 2 less than the maximum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For a sequence of numbers $p_1,p_2,...p_{2n}$, which is a permutated sequence of integers between $1$ and $2n$, determine its "score" as $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}|p_k-k|$.
Find the maximum amount of the "score".
Also how many permutations of the number sequence are there in which the score is 2 less than the maximum.

I can guess the maximum is $4(n!)^2$(I'm not sure). But I have no idea how to find this.

Comment: Which permutation is  giving you that score of $4(n!)^2$ ?

Comment: I think $2n,2n-1,2n-2,....,3,2,1$ does.

Comment: Just to check: The score sum is for $k$ from $1$ to $n$, not $1$ to $2n$?

Comment: Do the case of $n=1$ again, you will see the formula you provide does not match. Do small cases to establish the guess first.

Comment: Sorry the sum is for k from 1 to 2n.I've edited it.

Comment: By trying  $n=1$ , I've noticed that it doesn't match. Thanks for telling me. Now I have no idea how to find this.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diaconis and Graham](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1977.tb01624.x) studied this problem probabilistically and called it a disarray problem. If we have two permutations $\pi$ and $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, they introduce the $D$ measure as
$$D_n(\pi, \sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^n |\pi(i)-\sigma(i)|.$$
They use [Feller's representation](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Probability+Theory+and+Its+Applications%2C+Volume+1%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471257080) of the number of cycles of a permutation as a sum of independent random variables to obtain that
$$\max D_n = \Big[\frac{n^2}{2}\Big],$$
where $[x]$ is the floor of $x$. They gracefully write

> this representation and standard theorems from probability theory easily imply (...) the results listed in Table I.

I have spent the last hour trying to figure out these simple implications without success. However, this problem was also given by [Knuth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896850), problem 5.1.1.28, which he called the $\textit{total disorder}$ problem and I will base this solution on his approach. Let
$$td(\pi) = \sum_{k=1}^n |\pi(k)-k|$$
denote the total disorder of the permutation $\pi = a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n$ and let $inv(\pi)$ denote the number of $\text{inverses}$ of $\pi$, i.e., the number of pairs of elements $(a_i, a_j)$, such that $i < j$ and $a_i > a_j$. Note, for example, that $inv(\pi) = 0$ if and only if $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, \dots, a_n = n$. This is also the only sequence for which $td(\pi) = 0$.

We will find connection between $td(\pi)$ and $inv(\pi)$. Firstly, notice that if we swap any two adjacent elements in $\pi$, the value of $td(\pi)$ either does not change or changes by $\pm 2$, so
$$td(\pi) \leq 2inv(\pi).$$

Also, as each inverse introduces a 'perturbation' into the formula for $td$, we have
$$td(\pi) \geq inv(\pi).$$

This can be shown more formally, which I leave as an exercise. Now let:

- $j$ be the smallest element, such that $j \neq a_j$ ($j$ is not in its own place) and let $a_k = j$,
- $l$ be the largest element such that $l < k$ and $a_l \geq k$.

Then, if we swap $a_k$ with $a_l$, the total number of inverses in $\pi$ decreases by $2(k-l)-1$, and the total disorder decreases by $2(k-l)$. This means that if we need $m$ swaps of elements to sort a permutation $\pi$, then
$$td(\pi) = inv(\pi)+m.$$

The above reasoning also implies that, as the relation between the number of swaps and the total disorder is linear, we can use a permutation that requires a maximum number of swaps. From the linearity of this relation, we can select a permutation with a maximal number of inverses. So, the permutation $\pi_{max} = n(n-1)(n-2)\dots 21$ will give us the best result. Now, in the original question, we have $2n$ elements, so the reverse of the natural ordering

- has $\binom{2n}{2}$ inverses,
- requires $n$ swaps.

So
$$\max_{\pi \in S^n} td(\pi) = td(\pi_{max}) = \binom{2n}{2}+n = 2n^2$$

I believe that counting the number of permutations giving the score $2n^2-2$ should also be easier now.